# apropos plugin popup

Tags: android, android-studio, apropos

I'm facing a weird issue with Android Studio 3.2.1 on Mac Mojave wherein when I press Cmd + Shift + A to search action an annoying yellow popup appears and doesn't let me use search actions functionality. Any fixes for this issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Disable terminal shortcut "Search man Page Index in Terminal" to fix the issue. 
[image]

Comment: Helped me too, thanks. To add a few buzzwords: Android Studio Search Actions automatically executes

Comment: Note this is part of the OSX settings. The item is found under the heading Text and you may need to expand that category to see it all.

Comment: To add some more search terms which I was searching for: apropos show bottom

Comment: For the slow witted amongst us (like me), the path to fix this is: System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services -> uncheck Open man Page Index in Terminal